# Applying CSS through jQuery to a div called by Javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="someUrl"></script>
</div>
```

That script generates a div with some links inside of it so it's like:

```
<div>
    <div>
    <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to style those links to be a certain color with jQuery because that's the way the page was developed.

Right now I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("div a").css("color","#ffffff");
    });
</script>
```

The only browser that changes the links to white is Firefox because, I believe, FF loads pages differently and is applying these styles after the script creates the div?  How do I make this work across all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Code below works, I guess this is what you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#click").click(function(){
     $("#maindiv").append("<div><div><a href='example.com'>AAA</a></div></div>");
     $("#maindiv > div a").css("color","#ffffff");      
       });    
    });
</script>    


<div id="maindiv">
<div>
    <div>
    <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<a id="click" href="#">Click Here</a>
```

After your JS generates the div, you should then set the CSS, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming for some strange reason you are unable to use an external stylesheet, you could always add them inline, with your script, by adding `style="color: blue;"`.

Or failing that, make sure your selector is selecting what you really want. Can you put an id on that wrapping `div`, and then use a selector like `$('#my-div > div a')` (assuming you only want to add colour to the direct descendants).

Comment: It has to be applied this way because these divs are modular and can be called on different pages with different layouts, so the styles have to be changed accordingly.

I think it's a problem of when the styles are being added.  It's working in Firefox but no other browser.  I'm thinking the jQuery is being executed before the javascript creates the div, so the styles are essentially getting lost. Except in FF, the div must be created before the jQuery is executed.

Comment: CSS can handle that. It depends on how you include it, and how generic the containers are, and what you call them.